# How to dynamically update data attribute multiple times

Tags: jquery

I want to update an input of one field to be data attribute of another field. I manage to do it once, but doesn't work the second time.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
$('[data-key="hello"]').attr('data-key', $('[data-id="hi"]').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-id="hi">
<input data-key="hello">
<button>Click</button>
```

How do I make it update every time I click the button? Why doesn't it work every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use wrong approach. Because on every click **data-key** has been changed. You should use class or id.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
$('#hello').attr('data-key', $('[data-id="hi"]').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-id="hi">
<input id="hello" data-key="hello">
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute to achieve it.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
   $('#hello').data('key', $('#hi').val());
   
   console.log($('#hello').data('key'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-id="hi" id="hi">
<input data-key="hello" id = "hello">
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: It seems like yours doesn't change at all when I inspect it. I found the problem, I was selecting the data attribute that already changed.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Tom Bomb